# How to change password of user in physical standby database Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, password, standby

Hi I am new to Oracle 11g, I have a physical standby database and a primary database of Oracle 11g on two different servers.

I have changed the passwords of users(schemas)like sys, sysman, system, users,etc. in primary database by using command :

"`SQL>alter user username identified by password`"

and the passwords have been successfully changed, but when I am trying the same thing with physical standby database , its creating oracle error
**`ORA-16000: database open for read-only access`**

And I don't want to change the physical standby database to primary i.e. cannot change it to open read - write mode .

Kindly provide some solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do realize the standby is a "physical" copy of the primary (read-only in this case)? If you change the password in the primary, the changes will be propagated to the standby also. You can not change such things in a physical standby independently.

Comment: I am using unmanaged physical standby database, i copy archive logs from primary server to  standby server and then sync standby server, you means next tym when i will sync standby server , the password will change automatically ?

Comment: The concept is similar, and yes, it will change automatically.